# Gracefully shutdown http.Server{}

Tags: go

Good day, everyone!

I want to learn the proper way to gracefully shutdown a `http.Server{}`. Some answers I found would not handle `ctrl-c` signals. Others would handle it, but it would lock on the channel read if the server closed itself.

To handle the above situations, I came up with this template. I'm not very experienced when system signals, http.Server and concurrency are all mixed.

So my questions are:

- Am I missing something?
- Could I remove the `sync.WaitGroup{}`, `kill` and `closed` channels? And let the program exits and discard the goroutine?

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    log.Print("main: start")
    srv := http.Server{
        Addr: ":8080",
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello!!!")
        }), 
    }   

    stop := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    kill := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    closed := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    signal.Notify(stop, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(kill, os.Kill)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        log.Print("goroutine: start")

        select {
        case <-stop:
            log.Print("goroutine: interrupt signal: server shutdown: start")

            if err := srv.Shutdown(context.TODO()); err != nil {
                log.Print("goroutine: interrupt signal: server shutdown: ", err)
            }   

            log.Print("goroutine: interrupt signal: server shutdown: exit")
            // do nothing
        case <-kill:
            log.Print("goroutine: kill signal")
            // do nothing?
        case <-closed:
            log.Print("goroutine: server closed")
            // do nothing
        }   

        log.Print("goroutine: exit")
    }() 

    log.Print("server: listen start")
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Print("server error: ", err)
    }   
    log.Print("server: listen exit")

    closed <- struct{}{}

    wg.Wait()

    log.Print("main: exit")
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem or question, this might be a post better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. It makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Things to think about, you can’t handle a SIGKILL at all, and why have `closed` if you are already exiting?

Comment: @JimB The `closed` is to be overzealous on gracefully exiting everything.